# How to execute (Login) button on specific website?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I found this VBA code online and it works on Facebook for example.

On https://www.solarmanpv.com/portal/LoginPage.aspx it does not work. It opens Internet Explorer, puts the credentials on the right places but won't press login.

Error '424' is shown on VBA when I try to run.

```
Sub LoginViaBrowser()
    Dim Dc_Usuario As String
    Dim Dc_Senha As String
    Dim Dc_URL As String
    Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer 'Referencie "Microsoft Internet Controls"

    objIE.Visible = True

    Dc_Usuario = "user@email.com"
    Dc_Senha = "pass"
    Dc_URL = "https://www.solarmanpv.com/portal/LoginPage.aspx"

    objIE.Navigate2 Dc_URL

    Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    objIE.document.all("uNam").innertext = Dc_Usuario
    objIE.document.all("uPwd").innertext = Dc_Senha

    objIE.document.all("login").submit

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is probably a dupe. You need a proper page load wait _While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend_  and then use ids to target the login fields.

Comment: you should find suitable examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+login

Comment: The name and id of the login button are both `Loginning`, not `login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use F12 developer tools to check the html elements, then, you could find that the id of the login button is "Loginning", not "login".

Try to modify your code as below:

```
Sub LoginViaBrowser()
    Dim IE As Object

    Dim Dc_Usuario As String
    Dim Dc_Senha As String
    Dim Dc_URL As String

    Dim txtNam As Object, txtPwd As Object

    Dc_Usuario = "user@email.com"
    Dc_Senha = "pass"

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.solarmanpv.com/portal/LoginPage.aspx"

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        IE.Document.getElementById("uNam").Value = Dc_Usuario
        IE.Document.getElementById("uPwd").Value = Dc_Senha

        IE.Document.getElementById("Loginning").Click

    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: still missing a proper page load wait

Comment: Thank you! Its working perfectly now! Seriously this will make my life much easier, I really apreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling a click on it by id?

```
IE.Document.getElementById("Loginning").Click
```

Comment: Thanks, the code @Zhi LV - MSFT shared, he use this line and its working great now!